# looking for a name of a sci fi book with jellyfish aliens of different colors attacking military

Tags: story-identification

OK this is a hard one because I can only remember bits and pieces of the book. I don't believe it is the first in the series but in the beginning the book takes place on a planet in a fort.

The fort is about the be attacked by a swarm of jellyfish looking aliens; I believe they're black. After the fight, a recon team is sent out to look for the swarm. In another part in the book, the swarm attacks the ship. This time, the jellyfish aliens are gray. They are the meanest of the swarm. They can only be killed with fire, and they get into the ship, I believe, and the military members are rushing to different parts of the ship trying to destroy the aliens.

At the end of the book the aliens try to communicate with the humans in a building which was a castle and a amusement park.  My mind is fuzzy. I believe this was the third book in the series and on the cover has a ship with what looked like jelly fish around it. Please help this is driving me crazy!

Comment: It might help if you could tell us about when you read the book and about how old it was. Was it a paperback? American or British?